# how does qmake determine the compiler to use in Makefile?

Tags: qt, makefile, qt4

The qt source comes with some examples.
After downloading it from the internet, I go to the examples/painting/concentriccircles and run 'qmake' and it generates the Makefile (which sets CC=gcc) from the .pro file and after make, I can run the demo program concentriccircles on my CentOS machine. (running x86 code).

Now I have a project running Qt on a sparc machine running an OS and I already have the build tree set up. If I move the whole concentriccircles directory to somewhere in the build tree, when I run 'qmake', the generated Makefile sets the CC=sparc-xxx-gcc instead of just plain gcc(which is for x86 host). In fact, without moving the directory, if I run qmake from the sparc build tree, it makes the Makefile for sparc. (regardless of the .pro file)

How does qmake know that I'm building the qt program for sparc machine just from the location where I run qmake? Below is the concentriccircles.pro file.

```
HEADERS       = circlewidget.h \
                window.h
SOURCES       = circlewidget.cpp \
                main.cpp \
                window.cpp

# install
target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/painting/concentriccircles
sources.files = $$SOURCES $$HEADERS $$RESOURCES $$FORMS concentriccircles.pro
sources.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/painting/concentriccircles
INSTALLS += target sources

symbian {
    TARGET.UID3 = 0xA000A64A
    include($$QT_SOURCE_TREE/examples/symbianpkgrules.pri)
}
maemo5: include($$QT_SOURCE_TREE/examples/maemo5pkgrules.pri)
```

Comment: The compiler is specified during setting up build-environment. The compiler is not read from project specs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all you need to know which spec qmake is using by default. You can check this by doing

```
qmake -query QMAKE_MKSPECS
```

The result should be path containing all mkspecs i.e.

```
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs
```

Now you can check default mkspec:

```
ls -lah /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/default
```

Result (for my configuration)

```
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/default -> linux-g++-64
```

So clearly you can see that I have by default linux-g++-64 mkspec

Now let's see what's inside the spec:

```
cat /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/default/qmake.conf
```

Result:

```
#
# qmake configuration for linux-g++
#
# Written for GNU/Linux platforms that have both lib and lib64 directories,
# like the AMD Opteron.
#

MAKEFILE_GENERATOR  = UNIX
TARGET_PLATFORM     = unix
TEMPLATE        = app
CONFIG          += qt warn_on release incremental link_prl gdb_dwarf_index
QT          += core gui
QMAKE_INCREMENTAL_STYLE = sublib

QMAKE_CFLAGS        = -m64
QMAKE_LFLAGS        = -m64

include(../common/linux.conf)
include(../common/gcc-base-unix.conf)
include(../common/g++-unix.conf)


QMAKE_LIBDIR_X11      = /usr/X11R6/lib64
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL   = /usr/X11R6/lib64

load(qt_config)
```

As you can see it includes some other .conf files. In my configuration g++-unix.conf includes simply g++-base.conf so I'll get straight to it:

```
cat /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/g++-base.conf
```

Result:

```
#
# Qmake configuration for the GNU C++ compiler
#
# Before making changes to this file, please read the comment in
# gcc-base.conf, to make sure the change goes in the right place.
#
# To verify that your change has the desired effect on the final configuration
# you can use the manual test in tests/manual/mkspecs.
#

QMAKE_CC = gcc

QMAKE_LINK_C       = $$QMAKE_CC
QMAKE_LINK_C_SHLIB = $$QMAKE_CC

QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO += -O2 -g

QMAKE_CXX = g++

QMAKE_LINK       = $$QMAKE_CXX
QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB = $$QMAKE_CXX

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO += $$QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO

QMAKE_PCH_OUTPUT_EXT = .gch

QMAKE_CFLAGS_PRECOMPILE       = -x c-header -c ${QMAKE_PCH_INPUT} -o ${QMAKE_PCH_OUTPUT}
QMAKE_CFLAGS_USE_PRECOMPILE   = -include ${QMAKE_PCH_OUTPUT_BASE}
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_PRECOMPILE     = -x c++-header -c ${QMAKE_PCH_INPUT} -o ${QMAKE_PCH_OUTPUT}
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_USE_PRECOMPILE = $$QMAKE_CFLAGS_USE_PRECOMPILE
```

As you can see compiler is strictly defined by choosen qmake spec file. You can use different spec file by calling

```
qmake -spec SPEC_NAME
```

SPEC_NAME should be directory name inside `qmake -query QMAKE_MKSPECS`

Comment: I didn't say it works on Qt5 - on Qt5 there is no QMAKE_MKSPECS however mkspecs directory is still present (may be in different path) - still choosing "build env" for qmake is done by qmake -spec switch